# Similarity in two 2x2 Matrices and finding the S in A=SBS-1

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

I am doing something wrong here and I am not sure what.

The object of the exercise is to find the S for similar matrices $A$ and $B$.

$A=SBS^{-1}$

with $B=\begin{pmatrix}4& 1\\1& 2\end{pmatrix}$

and $A=\begin{pmatrix}1& 1\\-2& 5\end{pmatrix}$

I assumed it had something to do with the Eigenvectors and a basis built from them (because that is the current topic in the course), but it isn't working out. I only need the $S$, but I'd like the $S^{-1}$ as well, to better understand what's going on.

I've calculated the diagonal matrices for both and the corresponding $T$ and $T^{-1}$ transformation matrices, but no combination of them multiplied with $B=A$. Am I over complicating things?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is the diagonal matrix you computed?

Comment: If you calculated the diagonal matrices then you worked over the complex $\;\Bbb C\;$ , which is fine, and then you got $$P^{-1}AP=D\;,\;\;Q^{-1}BQ=D$$ same $\;D\;$ as the matrices are similar! And from here you get easily $$A=PDP^{-1}=P(Q^{-1}BQ)P\implies S=PQ^{-1}\;$$

Comment: This worked too! I think I understand what went wrong now. I started mixing the Ps and Qs up and listed the second Eigenvalue in the opposite order. I had to solve for B, so my S was $S=QP^{-1}$ with the following matrices. 
$P$
\begin{array}{cc}
1-\sqrt{2}& 1+\sqrt{2}\\
1& 1&
\end{array}

$P^{-1}$
\begin{array}{cc}
-1/2\sqrt{2}& 1+\sqrt{2}/2\sqrt{2}\\
1/2\sqrt{2}& -1+\sqrt{2}/2\sqrt{2}&
\end{array}

$Q$
\begin{array}{cc}
1+1/\sqrt{2}& 1-1/\sqrt{2}\\
1& 1&
\end{array}

$Q^{-1}$
\begin{array}{cc}
1/\sqrt{2}& 1/2-1/\sqrt{2}\\
-1/\sqrt{2}& 1/2+1/\sqrt{2}&
\end{array}

Answer (score 1):

$$S=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}\;,\;\;\;\text{and}\;\;\;A=SBS^{-1}\iff AS=SB\iff$$

$$AS=\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\\!\!-2&5\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}\;\;\,a+c&\;\;\,b+d\\-2a+5c&-2b+5d\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}4a+b&a+2b\\4c+d&c+2d\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}4&1\\1&2\end{pmatrix}$$

Well, now you "just have" a linear system in $\;4\;$ unknowns:

$$\begin{cases}a+c=4a+b\\b+d=a+2b\\-2a+5c=4c+d\\-2b+5d=c+2d\end{cases}$$

Solving it you get, for example,

$$S=\begin{pmatrix}1&\!\!-1\\2&0\end{pmatrix}\implies S^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}0&\frac12\\\!\!-1&\frac12\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: It works! Thank you so much! Now that you put it like that, I feel a little silly for calculating all these Eigenvectors.

Comment: @LisaEver Oh, no: eigenvectore, eigenvalues and etc, **is** the way. It's just that you didn't specify anything and in this case the eigenvalues are complexnon-real

Comment: @ Timbuc , $A=SBS^{-1}$ is not equivalent to $AS=SB$. In fact, to find a convenient solution $S$ is not a linear problem; it is a degree $n$ problem (obviously, when  $n=2$, the difficulty is hidden).

Answer (score 0):

$A=PDP^{−1}=P(Q^{−1}BQ)P⟹S=PQ^{−1}$

with $P$ and $Q$ built from the Eigenvectors.

$P$
\begin{matrix}
1-\sqrt{2}& 1+\sqrt{2}\\
1& 1&
\end{matrix}

$P^{-1}$
\begin{matrix}
-1/2\sqrt{2}& (1+\sqrt{2})/2\sqrt{2}\\
1/2\sqrt{2}& (-1+\sqrt{2})/2\sqrt{2}&
\end{matrix}

$Q$
\begin{matrix}
1+(1/\sqrt{2})& 1-(1/\sqrt{2})\\
1& 1&
\end{matrix}

$Q^{-1}$
\begin{matrix}
1/\sqrt{2}& (1/2)-(1/\sqrt{2})\\
-1/\sqrt{2}& (1/2)+(1/\sqrt{2})&
\end{matrix}